# iFrame in android application not allowing any network requests

Tags: android, ajax, angular, ionic-framework, iframe

**Details:**

- I have a production application built for the app stores (iOS and
  Android) and build for web.
- A client is using the web version in an iFrame within their
  application (Android and iOS).
- The web version is displayed correctly in iOS and Android.

**The issue:**

- All network requests done in the web version of my app (from the clients iFrame) are not working in **Android devices only**. When inspecting the request in Charles, the request do not show up at all.
- The requests go through as expected in iOS using the web version of my app.

I've looked at CSP meta tags, but none of them have made a difference:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

[Ionic-cant send http requests on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571303/ionic-cant-send-http-requests-on-device)

Is their anything obvious I am missing?

Here is the web version index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
<script data-ionic="inject">
    (function(w){var i=w.Ionic=w.Ionic||{};i.version='3.9.2';i.angular='5.2.11';i.staticDir='build/';})(window);
</script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#4e8ef7">
    <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;">
    <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker -->
    <script>
        if ( 'location' in window ) {
            if ( window.location.protocol === 'http:' ) {
                window.location.protocol = 'https:';
            }
        }
        if ( 'serviceWorker' in navigator ) {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register( 'service-worker.js' )
                .then( () => console.log( 'service worker installed' ) )
                .catch( err => console.error( 'Error', err ) );
        }
    </script>

    <link href="build/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


    <!-- Ionic's root component and where the app will load -->
    <ion-app></ion-app>

    <!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
    <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

    <!-- The vendor js is generated during the build process
    It contains all of the dependencies in node_modules -->
    <script src="build/vendor.js"></script>

    <!-- The main bundle js is generated during the build process -->
    <script src="build/main.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would need to check logcat to see if there are any messages, but if I had to guess I'd say it's "by design" to prevent mixed security contexts via iframe.

Comment: It is by design to only do that on android devices?

Comment: Android and IOS are different codebases. There is no requirement or expectation that they behave the same.However as I mentioned, this is just a guess. The only way you're going to be able to tell what's actually happening is to examine the logs and possibly run in a debugger.

Comment: Yes but that would imply that all iFrames with https requests opened within an android app are guaranteed to fail. I know that's not true.It seems like something specific to the clients android app that isnt allowing certain requests to be made.

Comment: If you have an https page and embed an iframe with an http source, I suspect you'll find that it's not displayed or presents a warning. The current version of chrome, for example, silently drops the content, with a small warning icon.